# Exists $f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that $G(x, t)\geq f(x) \vert t\vert^{\theta} -\alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $g:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that
$$ g(x, \cdot)t\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto g(x, t)\in\mathbb{R} \ \mbox{ is continuous for a.e. } x\in\Omega$$
and
$$g(\cdot, t)x\in\Omega\mapsto g(x,)\in\mathbb{R} \ \mbox{ is Lebesgue measurable for all } t\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Define
$$G(x, t) = \int_{0}^t g(x, s) ds.$$
Suppose there exists $\theta >2$ such that
$$0 <\theta G(x, t)\leq g(x, t) t.$$
Could anyone help me to understand why the above condition implies that
$$G(x, t)\geq f(x) \vert t\vert^{\theta} -\alpha,$$
with $f(x) >0$ a.e. in $\Omega$ and $f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, while $\alpha$ denotes a positive constant?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is only a hint, not a full answer.)

Consider only the case $t>0$ (the case $t<0$ should be similar).
Let $f(x) := G(x, 1) = \int_0^1 g(x, t)\, dt$. By assumption, we have that $f(x) > 0$.
Moreover, the function $t\mapsto G(x, t)$ satisfies the differential inequality
$$
\begin{cases}
G' \geq \frac{\theta}{t}\, G, & t > 0, \\
G(1) = f(x),
\end{cases}
$$
which gives
$$
G(x) \geq f(x) \exp \int_1^t \frac{\theta}{s}\, ds = f(x) \, t^\theta,
$$
for every $t\geq 1$.

The range $t\in [0,1]$ should be adjusted using the constant $\alpha$.
In any case, I think that you need to assume something like
$$
\textrm{esssup} \{|g(x,t)|; x\in\Omega, t\in [-1,1]\} < \infty 
$$
to obtain both the existence of the constant $\alpha$ and the boundedness of $f$.
(I don't know if this condition can be deduced from your assumptions.)